# $7^{21}\cdot 2^{50}+a$ is divisible by $9$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find the smallest value of $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $7^{21}\cdot 2^{50}+a$ divisible by $9$.

The only thing I know is that an integer is divisible by $9$ is the sum of its digits is divisible by $9$.

Comment: Do you know the phi function

Comment: What is the relationship between $a$ and $k\,$?

Comment: I know something, but not too much.

Comment: @John Bentin My fault, I made some changes.

Comment: Hint: $\bmod 9\!:\  7\equiv -2\,$ and $\,2^3\equiv -1\,$ so $\,2^6\equiv 1\ \ $